# expand my regular expression

Tags: sql-server, regex

I need help for my regular expression in ms sql
Here is my code

```
SET @sql='MERGE [WarehouseMgmt].[DimReportServerUserEntries] AS Target
    USING( 
              SELECT REX.[Value],RS.LogEntryId FROM '+@server+'.[dbo].[ExecutionLogStorage] RS 
              CROSS APPLY [WarehouseMgmt].RegExpMatches(RS.[Parameters], ''(?<=User=).+?(?=&)'') REX
             -- WHERE RS.LogEntryId > @LastId
          ) AS Source
    ON Source.LogEntryId=Target.SourceOrigId
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT 
        (
            [UserName],
            [SourceOrigId]

        )
        VALUES 
        (
            Source.[Value],
            Source.[LogEntryId]
        )
```

In ReportServer.[dbo].[ExecutionLogStorage] table is [Parameter] field, and inside Parameters i have this:

```
&User:isnull=true& but there also can be &User=somename& , or thare can be no UserName at all
```

For &User=somename& i handle that in my reg. expression

I want to update my table [WarehouseMgmt].[DimReportServerUserEntries] so i will have if UserName is &User:isnull=true& UserName = <'UNKNOWN'> and SourceOrigId = -1

Comment: `(?<=User)(?:=|:).+?(?=&)` ?

Comment: I need to update my table If i have &User:isnull=true& or if there is no UserName in [Parameters] .Can you help me ?

Comment: `(?:(?<=User)(?:=|:).+?(?=&))|(?:(?!User).)*` ?

Comment: no definitely not . I got 3 records for each row

Comment: Need regular expression for case : &User:isnull=true& and if there is no UserName in [Parameters]. I will have two merges one for UserName=somevalue and onther for &User:isnull=true& and no value